# PDF viewer - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed Visual Studio Code can be used to view PDFs.
[PDF Viewer with tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/20675/pdf-viewer-with-tabs/1734208#1734208)

This is using the extension "vscode-pdf".

My question was: Is there any way to export a PDF page to image, either in the same extension or another one.

Comment: Hi, just following up on this, if someone can assist in any way.

Comment: Is it possible to refer me to another forum which could assist with this type of query.